# Converting depth image from millimeter to meters in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, ros

This seems really easy but I am getting an error with OpenCV image processing. The input image is a depth image having `CV_16UC1` encoding (depth values are in millimeter). I want to convert depth values to meters as shown below-

```
auto img_m = img_mm * 0.001f; // convert to meter (SI units)
```

Finally, I need depth values of a few pixels. Therefore, I am using the `mat.at()` function in the following way-

```
// let say we want to get the depth value at (0, 0)
int pixel_x = 0;
int pixel_y = 0;
auto depth = img_m.at<unsigned short>(pixel_y, pixel_x);
```

Unfortunately, it is showing the following compilation error-

```
error: ‘class cv::MatExpr’ has no member named ‘at’
       auto depth = img_m.at<unsigned short>(pixel_y, pixel_x);
```

Out of curiosity, I checked the data type of both the images and found the following-

```
std::cout << "cvtype(img_mm): " << img_mm.type() << std::endl;
std::cout << "size(img_mm): " << img_mm.size() << " size(img_m): " << img_m.size() << std::endl;
std::cout << "type(img_mm): " << typeid(img_mm).name() << " type(img_m): " << typeid(img_m).name() << std::endl;

cvtype(img_mm): 2
size(img_mm): [640 x 480] size(img_m): [640 x 480]
type(img_mm): N2cv3MatE type(img_m): N2cv7MatExprE
```

**Here, we can see that `img_m` is `N2cv7MatExprE`, which is causing the compilation error.**

As a workaround, instead of converting `img_mm` to `img_m`, I am multiplying the depth value as following-

```
auto depth_mm = img_mm.at<unsigned short>(pixel_y, pixel_x);
auto depth_m = depth_mm * 0.001f; // convert to meter (SI units)
```

However, I want to know why scalar multiplication is going crazy!!!

Below are the environment details-

- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS OS
- ROS Indigo (Default OpenCV shipped along ROS)
- OpenCV 2.4.8
- CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION 4.8.5

Comment: Don't use `auto`, e.g. `cv::Mat1f img_m = img_mm * 0.001f;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `auto` to  let compiler deduce the type for `img_m` and compiler deduces it correctly as `cv::MatExpr`. Multiplying `cv::Mat` and a sclalar results in `cv::MatExpr` that can be casted to `cv::Mat`. To avoid this problem you should specify the type for `img_m`:

```
cv::Mat img_m = img_mm * 0.001f; // convert to meter (SI units)
```